# how the best way to create project with maven on eclips?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

i know there are 2 methode to create project with Maven.

1. Create Dynamic project on eclipse and convert it into maven project
2. Create Maven project with command line and then import the project into eclips.

i always do the 1. choise.

Comment: Or just create maven project directly - all you need is m2e extension.

Answer (score 2):

If You have latest eclipse IDE then its very simple.

- Go to Create new Project wizard and search maven project. (if its old eclipse IDE then you probably need to install m2e plug in from market place).
- select maven project and next. Check (Create a simple project) if you want customization other wise just click Next and You will be presented a number of ready made archtypes.
- For simple console projects you can chose maven-archtype-quickstart. or what ever project you want to create.
- Now Give groupId e.g. com.yourcompany or com.yourprojectgroup and artifactId e.g. projectname-alias . and Click Finish.

First Time eclipse will create local repo if its not already created and then put default dependencies defined by provided pom in your local repo. Further you just need maven knowledge to customize project. e.g. New Dependencies and build system etc.

I hope this will clear your mind. I prefer this way because its fast and easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new project in Eclipse (at least in Mars or Neon), you can choose "Maven Project" and get everything you need. Don't use eclipse goals of Maven. They are deprecated.